# Set session with Jquery and PhP always work on second loading [Opencart]

Tags: php, ajax, session, opencart

Im trying to detect window width on homepage loading with jquery and pass it to php with ajax and than return it with php in the template

if i print $_SESSION in template i can see there is no new_session on 1st page load if i refresh again i can see it , how to sort the problem on first home page load to set the session ?

in template\common\home.tpl

```
  $(window).on('load', function(){
var width = $(window).width();
var divice = '';
if (width < 768) {
  divice = 'mobile';
}else if (width > 768 && width < 992) {
  divice = 'tablet';
}else if (width > 992) {
  divice = 'pc';
}

$.ajax({
  url: 'index.php?route=common/home/setDivice',
  type: 'post',
  data: 'divice='+divice,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(){

  }
});
})
```

in catalog\controller\common\home.php

```
public function setDivice(){

    $this->session->data['new_session'] = $_POST['divice'];

}
```

Comment: The problem you've got is that you're updating the value in the session via Ajax - but because PHP has finished working before anything is rendered onscreen you've not really got any way to access the `$_SESSION` variable... short of making another Ajax request... which makes this whole process overly-convoluted. Just use the JS *device* variable value... better yet, if you can do it all with CSS (e.g. it's just display-stuff), do so and don't bother PHP with something that it really shouldn't be concerned with.

Comment: @CD001 the problem is in DB are set 3 different images of each block depend of divice width and in array i have like $block_image['mobile'], $block_image['tablet'] $block_image['pc'] and i should change them depend of divice width, any idea how to do it ?

Comment: I think you're over-complicating it... just use one very big image at very, very low quality - it keeps the filesize down while using the fact that most modern browsers leverage the GPU to anti-alias images when they're dynamically resized these days... which remove artefact compression problems. Or return all 3 image paths in the JSON and let JS decide which to use. I honestly think this is best handled client-side; there's no reason for PHP to know/care what type of device is viewing the page.